# Fill a corner of the selected ComboBox cell with the main color JavaFX, CSS

Tags: css, javafx

Is it possible to fill corner of the selected ComboBox cell with the main color (It remains white instead of #2f4f4f).

Here is my CSS code:

```
 .combo-box {   
     -fx-border-color: #000000;
     -fx-border-width: 1;
     -fx-background-radius: 0;
     -fx-background-color: #2f4f4f;
     -fx-font-family: "Arial";
     -fx-font-size: 12px;
     -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
     -fx-background-insets: 0;
     -fx-alignment: center;
     -fx-content-display: center;
 }

 .combo-box > .cell {   
     -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
     -fx-alignment: center;
 }

 .combo-box:hover {   
     -fx-background-color: #87cefa;
 }

 .combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell {
     -fx-background-color: #2f4f4f;
     -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
     -fx-text-alignment: center;
 }

 .combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:selected, 
 .combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:selected:hover {
     -fx-background: #2f4f4f;
     -fx-background-color: #87cefa;
     -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
     -fx-text-alignment: center;
 }

 .combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:hover {
     -fx-background-color: #87cefa;
     -fx-text-alignment: center;
     -fx-background-radius: 10.0;
 }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhF1C.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a good first question, however, it would be much better posed as a [mcve]. Once you're done, [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your CSS style:

```
.combo-box-popup .list-view {
    -fx-background-color: #2f4f4f;
}
```